# Ubuntu kernal panic libc6 screenshot attached

Tags: kernel, glibc

I was installing some packages, 'create repo' I think. I guess this must have messed up my libc6 installation as now I am receiving a kernal panic when I restart my box. Complaining about missing libc6 libraries.

I've tried a couple of guides on the internet which said to download the right libc6.deb and extract to my root directoy using a livecd but it didn't change anything.

I have a livecd so can run commands from there.

A screenshot of the panic can be found here https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOzpb.jpg.

Thanks! Will

Comment: Did you install it through `apt-get`? Were you using an external repo? What version of Ubuntu is this (looks like Saucy, which means there needs to be version 2.17)? Also, don't replace `libc6` manually, since everything depends on it.

Comment: Originally I was installing packages with YUM because I was trying to set up a local yum repository. I ran 'yum install createrepo', left my box for a while and came back to the lock screen as expected about an hour later. My password wouldn't work so I had to hard power down and restarted to the kernal panic. I then followed the steps here to no avail http://askubuntu.com/questions/335527/kernel-panic-after-attempting-to-install-glibc.
I was using external repos yes which could be the problem. 
I have 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I think I may be able to do a reinstall if I can get chroot to work. But in true linux style I'm now stuck with  a new problem: libtermcap.so.2: cannot open shared object error while running chroot.

Comment: You'll probably have to blow the partition away and do a fresh install of Ubuntu. Was `yum` working as root, or was it running under your username?

Comment: It was running as root under sudo. Was the mistake here using yum?

Comment: Highly likely. I'm not sure what repository `yum` was using, but it probably realized that `createrepo` has dependencies that aren't fulfilled. (`apt` and `yum` are two completely different systems that happen to have somewhat-similar syntax, and it's not expected that a single system has both systems installed.) These dependencies probably went all the way up to the `libc` modules. Therefore, it installed those modules, overwriting the Ubuntu version and breaking compatibility with pretty much everything Ubuntu.

Comment: If you want to use `yum`, I suggest you use it inside a CentOS chroot or (to be safe) in a VM.

Comment: Right I see, that does make sense. I've chrooted in now and when I try to run commands I get the following:

root@ubuntu:/# dpkg -i libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb 

dpkg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by dpkg)

dpkg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by dpkg)

dpkg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by dpkg)

dpkg: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by dpkg)
......

Is there no way you can think of to get around the missing glibc_* not found errors, Can I install it from somewhere perhaps.Thanks